# Code returns same line multiple times instead of multiple lines

Tags: python, csv, output

What I'm trying to do is to open two CSV files and print only the lines in which the content of a column in file 1 and file 2 match. I already know that I should end up with 14 results, but instead the first line of the CSV file I'm working with gets printed 14 times. Where did I go wrong?

```
file1 = open("../dir/file1.csv", "r")
for line in file1:
    file1splitted = line.strip().split(",")

    file2 = open("../dir/file2.csv", "r")
    for line in file2:
        file2splitted = line.strip().split(",")

        for line in file1:
            if file1splitted[0] == file2splitted [2]:
                print (file1splitted[0],file1splitted[1], file2splitted[6], file2splitted[10], file2splitted[12])

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Comment: You're trampling over your `line` loop variable within your nested loops. Whether that is the cause of the issue, I'm not sure, but I suggest using different names for clarity

Comment: Be carefull while opening files inside for loops. It might cause you some troubles. (Not sure if this is the problem there)

Comment: I prefer using `open` with a `with` statement so that I know it will close even if an error occurs: `with open("../dir/file1.csv", "r") as file1:`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for reading these files because splitting on commas is not reliable; it's fine for a single CSV column to contain values that themselves include commas.

I've added a couple of things to try make this cleaner and to help you move forward in your learning:

1. I've used the `with` *context manager* that automatically closes a file once you're done reading it. No need for `.close()`
2. I've packaged the csv reading code into a function. Now we only need to write that part once and we can call the function with any file.
3. I've used the `csv` module to read the file. This will return a nested list of rows, each inner list representing a single row.
4. I've used a *list comprehension* which is a neater way of writing a `for` loop that creates a list. In this case, it's a list of all the items in the first column of file_1.
5. I've converted the list in Point 4 into a *set*. When we iterate through file_2, we can very quickly check whether a row value has been seen in file_1 (`set` lookup is O(1) rather than having to iterate through file_1 every single time).

The indices I print are from my own test files, you will need to adapt them to your own use-case.

```
import csv

def read_csv(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as infile: # Context manager to auto-close files at end
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        #next(reader) remove the hash if you want to drop the headers
        return list(reader)


file_1 = read_csv('file_1.csv')
file_2 = read_csv('file_2.csv')

# Make a set of file_1 column 0 with a list comprehension
file_1_vals = set([item[0] for item in file_1])

# Now iterate through file_2
for row in file_2:
    if row[2] in file_1_vals:
        print(row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file1 = open("../dir/file1.csv", "r")
file2 = open("../dir/file2.csv", "r")
for line in file1:
    file1splitted = line.strip().split(",")
    for line in file2:
        file2splitted = line.strip().split(",")
        if file1splitted[0] == file2splitted [2]:
            print (file1splitted[0],file1splitted[1], file2splitted[6], file2splitted[10], file2splitted[12])

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

if you provide your csv files then I can help you more.

Comment: This isn't a good way to read CSV files. We have the csv module for this task

Comment: @roganjosh you are very correct, my focus was on logic , why MacRupp was getting wrong result